# Get button name in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get the name of a button selected in a variable, and do something after (change the content of a `<p>`).

```
<form>
    <button name="paypal" class="moyen-payement-button" ng-class="{actif: actifSelected.selectedButton === 1}" ng-click="actifSelected.select(1)">
        <img src="images/payement-methods/paypal.svg" alt="Paypal" class="paypal" />
    </button>
    <button name="creditCard" class="moyen-payement-button" ng-class="{actif: actifSelected.selectedButton === 2}" ng-click="actifSelected.select(2)">
         <img src="images/payement-methods/credit-card.svg" alt="Carte de crédit" class="creditCard" />
    </button>
</form>

<p>Name of my button: </p>
<p>1</p>
```

The `<p>` with "1" have to change in "2" if the button creditCard is selected, I've find `ng-show` / `ng-hide` but I think I can simply modify the content of a `<p>` without creating another `<p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass $event to ng-click:

```
  <button name="hello" ng-click="myFunction($event, 2)">Test</button>
  <p>{{btnName}}</p>
  <p>{{arg1}}</p>
```

With this in the controller:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(e, arg1) {
  $scope.arg1 = arg1;
  console.log(e.target.name);
  $scope.btnName = e.target.name;
}
```

See this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0SwOE8tHxazmmKKz9BJz?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
<button ng-click="actifSelected.select($event,1)"></button>
```

And in your controller, you can use $event to trigger element

```
$scope.actifSelected.select = function($event, value) {
    var button = angular.element($event.currentTarget);
    var buttonName = button.attr("name");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following expression:

```
<p>{{ actifSelected.selectedButton === 1 ? '1' : '2' }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's help me a lot ! :)
Do you know how to get the button name selected in angular too ?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any "pure" angular approach for this, you should use jQuery or any other DOM manipulation using JS, of-course you should use directive when using DOM manipulation, don't to it in the controller

Comment: @Gouigoui, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Just display the selectedButton variable display in your

```
 <p>{{actifSelected.selectedButton}}</p>
```